# How can i get the entire xml node with javascript under Chrome?

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome

```
var xml = '<books><book><id>1</id></book></books>';
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
$(xmlDoc).find("book").each(function(){
  alert($(this));
});
```

What i want to see is:

```
<book><id>1</id></book>
```

In IE, i can use $(this)[0].xml. But in Chrome, there's no xml property.
What should I do then?

Thanks.

Comment: Ah, your formatting changes the question. (The importance of formatting correctly in the first place! :-) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the browser's built-in `XMLSerializer` implementation (present in the current versions of all major browsers, including IE 9):

```
function serializeXmlNode(xmlNode) {
    if (typeof window.XMLSerializer != "undefined") {
        return new window.XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlNode);
    } else if (typeof xmlNode.xml != "undefined") {
        return xmlNode.xml;
    }
    return "";
}

var xml = '<books><book><id>1</id></book></books>';
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
$(xmlDoc).find("book").each(function(){
    alert( serializeXmlNode(this) );
});
```

References:

- [W3C spec](http://domparsing.spec.whatwg.org/)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XMLSerializer)
- [IE 9 support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/15/domparser-and-xmlserializer-in-ie9-beta.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

<s>If you want to see `1` (the text of the `id` element within the `book` element), use</s>

```
alert($(this).find('id').text());
```

Live Example | Source

*(Your formatting completely changes the question -- the importance of formatting correctly in the first place!)*

**Update**:

<s>I believe the only way to get this (other than writing your own DOM-to-XML serializer)</s> *(no, there's [another, probably better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13193743/157247) way)* is to wrap it in another element and use `html`:

```
alert($("<x>").append(this).html()); // <== Probably dangerous
```

...but that will *move* the element out of the original document. So you can avoid that by cloning:

```
alert($("<x>").append(this.cloneNode(true)).html());
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/enubom/3) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/enubom/3/edit)

Comment: Modern browsers implement `XMLSerializer`, which does the job properly.

Comment: Thanks T.J. I didn't expect you would reply in such a short notice. I realized the formatting error right after the question was posted and corrected at once.